Using required parameters with SqliteAsyncConnection.Table<T>
I have a model class with a couple of required fields, to avoid the null warning:
public class CategoryTable
{
    public CategoryTable() { }  

    [Column("id")]
    public required int Id { get; set; }

    [Column("name")]
    public required string Name { get; set; }
}

I then have a method to query the SqliteAsyncConnection database using the model:
public async Task<List<CategoryTable>> GetCategoryAsync<CategoryTable>()
{ 
    return await _database.Table<CategoryTable>().ToListAsync();
}

But I get CS0310 on Table<CategoryTable>():

CategoryTable must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless constructor in order to use it as parameter T in the generic type or method SQLiteAsyncConnection.Table<T>()

So I change the method to add a where CategoryTable : class, new() and CS0310 is solved:
public async Task<List<CategoryTable>> GetCategoryAsync<CategoryTable>() where CategoryTable : class, new()
{ 
    return await _database.Table<CategoryTable>().ToListAsync();
}

But then when I call the method:
await DatabaseConn.GetCategoryAsync<CategoryTable>();

I now get CS9040 on the calling line:

CategoryTable cannot satisfy the new() constraint on parameter CategoryTable in the generic type or or method IDatabaseService.GetCategoryAsync<CategoryTable>() because CategoryTable has required members.

I'm guessing I cannot use required parameters with the SQLite Table and Query methods and instead just need to live with the null warnings, or use int? & string?.
But I am hoping that it is just something I'm not seeing, and someone can point me in the right direction.

Which library do you use? Specify its full name. Add a tag.

Hi @AlexanderPetrov, I'm using sqlite-net-pcl and SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_green. Only sqlite-net-pcl was available as a tag, which I've added. Thanks.
